# How can I call recur in an if conditional in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to solve the *count a sequence* excercise at [4clojure.com](http://4clojure.com/problem/22#prob-title). The excercise is to count the number of elements in a collection without using the `count` function.

I thought I can do this via recursion, by the usage of `rest`. If what I get isn't empty, I return `1 + recur on the sequence rest returned`. The problem is, that I end up getting

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
Can only recur from tail position
```

even though I'm calling `recur` as the very last statement.

```
(fn [coll] (let [tail (rest coll)]
             (if (empty tail)
               1
               (+ 1 (recur tail)))))
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last statement is the addition, not the call to `recur`, which is why it doesn't work. The fact that it's inside an if has nothing to do with it. `(fn [coll] (let [tail (rest coll)] (+ 1 (recur tail))))` wouldn't work either.

The usual way to turn a function like this into a tail-recursive one is to make the function take a second argument, which holds the accumulator for the value you're adding up and then recurse like this: `(recur tail (+ acc 1))` instead of trying to add 1 to the result of `recur`.

As a general rule: If you're doing anything to the result of `recur` (like for example adding 1 to it), it can't be in a tail position, so it won't work.

Answer (score 6):

The error that you are getting is pointing out that your final expression of `(+ 1 (recur tail))` is not tail-call-optimization optimizable (is that a word?). The problem is that it needs to keep a bunch of `(+ 1 ...)` expressions on the stack in order to evaluate result of the function. Tail call optimization can only occur if the value of the called function is the *only* thing needed to know the return of the function making the call.

What you are trying to write is pretty much a `fold`. In this case the function should pass along the rest of the collection as well as the count so far.

```
(fn [count coll] (let [tail (rest coll)]
    (if (empty tail)
        count
        (recur (+ 1 count) tail)))))
```