# Nested recur statements

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Why doesn't the following snippet of code print "1" to the console?

```
(loop
  [i 0]
  (println (if (= i 0) (recur 1) i)))
```

Instead, it throws `clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Can't recur here at line 3` in the REPL.  Are nested `(recur..)` statements like this not allowed in Clojure(Script)?

Answer (score 3):

Correct, "nested recur statements" are not allowed in any Clojure dialect. The alternate behavior described in a comment (recur "halts and dismisses the execution of its parent statements") would work as an alternate language design choice, but would probably be a lot more confusing to read.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you try to print the result of (recur 1), which doesn't make sense. I think you probably meant to do (recur 1) if i==0, and print i otherwise, as follows:

```
(loop [i 0]
   (if (= i 0) (recur 1) (println i)))
```

Comment: Yes, that's the natural way to do it. I was trying to figure out if `(recur ...)` halts and dismisses the execution of its parent statements. It doesn't seem like this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

See [Clojure: What exactly is tail position for recur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813497/clojure-what-exactly-is-tail-position-for-recur) - you can only use `recur` from a "tail position" in Clojure. In this case, `recur` is not in a tail position because it is not the last thing to be evaluated in this function - the `println` would be evaluated after the call to `recur`.